# Count 2 columns by the same grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I'm trying to get two counts of separate columns for data in one table.

I have a database that tracks issues, and one table, Issue, has the 2 relevant columns that each contain a date. Very similar to the following.

```
DateOpened  DateClosed
2015-01-08  2015-01-08
2015-01-08  2015-01-08
2015-01-06  2015-01-08
2015-01-06  2015-01-08
2015-01-04  2015-01-07
2015-01-02  2015-01-07
2015-01-02  2015-01-07
```

My goal is to be able to count the number of entries opened and closed on each date. An example of the expected output from above would be.

```
Date          CountDateOpened CountDateClosed
2015-01-08    2               4
2015-01-07    0               3 
2015-01-06    2               0
2015-01-05    0               0
2015-01-04    1               0
2015-01-03    0               0
2015-01-02    2               0
```

I know I need to group by Date, but there should be days where more issues are closed than opened, but my COUNT(DateClosed) never seems to exceed my Count(DateOpened). I am doing on the fly date conversions in the query, but I do not believe them to be relevant since I always round to the nearest day. Here is the query I'm running so far, skinned down for simplicity.

```
SELECT
    CREATEDATE AS [Date],
    COUNT(CREATEDATE) AS [Number Opened],
    COUNT(CLOSEDATE) AS [Number Closed]

FROM
     ISSUE

GROUP BY
     CREATEDATE

ORDER BY 
     [Date] DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use `union all` to create a single column for both dates and then group according to its type:

```
SELECT   `Date`, 
         COUNT(`open`) AS `CountDateOpened`
         COUNT(`closed`) AS `CountDateClosed`
FROM     (SELECT `DateOpened` AS `Date`, 1 AS `open`, NULL AS `closed`
          FROM   `issue`
          UNION ALL
          SELECT `DateClosed` AS `Date`, NULL AS `open`, 1 AS `closed`
          FROM   `issue`
         ) t
GROUP BY `Date`
ORDER BY `Date` DESC
```

Comment: Fine solution. Just need "ORDER BY date DESC"

Comment: @twylyc missed the `order by` in the OP's query - edited and added. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: this will not include `2015-01-05` and `2015-01-03` in output as it is not present in table

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select 
 d.dt,(select COUNT(DateOpened) ct from ISSUE where
CAST(DateOpened as DATE)=CAST(d.dt as DATE) )
,(select COUNT(DateClosed) ct from ISSUE where
CAST(DateClosed as DATE)=CAST(d.dt as DATE) )
from (
select number,DATEADD(D,number-7,GETDATE()) dt
 from master.dbo.spt_values sp
where type='P' and DATEADD(D,number-7,GETDATE())<'2015-01-09'
)
d
ORDER BY d.dt desc
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Date      DateOpened DateClosed
2015-01-08  2            4
2015-01-07  0            3
2015-01-06  2            0
2015-01-05  0            0
2015-01-04  1            0
2015-01-03  0            0
2015-01-02  2            0
```

Comment: @Strawberry yes... but he should use numbers table other wise it will be miss `2015-01-05` and `2015-01-03`

Answer (score 0):

Same as Mureinik's answer, just a little less typing...

```
SELECT date,SUM(status='opened') opened, SUM(status = 'closed') closed 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT dateopened date,'opened' status FROM my_table
       UNION ALL
       SELECT dateclosed,'closed' FROM my_table
     ) x
 GROUP  
    BY date DESC;
```